# Matlab parfor unclassified variables

Tags: matlab, parfor

The following code calculates the matrix elements of A from the vector v. I try to use `parfor` to speedup the calculation as the dimension of `v` is very large. I get an error of "The variable `A` in a `parfor` cannot be classified.". Any suggestions on how to solve the problem?

```
A = zeros(n,n);
for kk = 1:D
    % sk = <expressions...>
    % ek = <expressions...>
    parfor ll = 1:D
        % sl = <expressions...>
        % el = <expressions...>
        if (ek == el)
            A(sk,sl) = A(sk,sl) + v(kk) * v(ll);
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you distribute `A` over different cores but adjust its value by itself. How should a core know that the entry `A(sk,sl)` wasn't changed on a different core? It needs to check this, communicating with all other cores, eliminating any parallel computation, which is why MATLAB complains about it:
[image: MATLAB complaint]

You can avoid the problem by creating a copy of `A` outside the `parfor`-loop

```
A = zeros(n,n);
B = A;
for kk = 1:D
    % sk = <expressions...>
    % ek = <expressions...>
    parfor ll = 1:D
        % sl = <expressions...>
        % el = <expressions...>
        if (ek == el)
            B(sk,sl) = A(sk,sl) + v(kk) * v(ll);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, but this solution will most likely not produce the same output. The reason `A` is initialized with zeros and added to in the loop, is that multiple loop iterations will produce the same `(sk,sl)` values. If this were not the case, there would be no reason to add to `A`, since `A(sk,sl)` would just be zero. Your diagnostic is correct, but the solution would be to not use `parlor`. This is just not a task suitable for non-shared-memory parallelism.

Comment: yepp, that is true, @CrisLuengo. Without seeing the code, I cannot suggest any proper parallelized solution =(

Answer (score 0):

You could formulate this as a ["reduction"](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/reduction-variable.html) over `A` like this:

```
parfor ll 1:D
    % compute stuff...

    % Make a new matrix for the increment
    Aincrement = zeros(n, n);
    % Fill out the element of the increment
    Aincrement(sk, sl) = v(kk) * v(ll);
    % Increment the whole of A so that parfor can 
    % treat A as a reduction variable
    A = A + Aincrement;
end
```

This might well be inefficient if `n` is large.